# How can find deleted row in a table using ORA_ROWSCN function

Tags: oracle

How can we find a row which is deleted in Oracle table with help of ORA_ROWSCN. If a row is deleted we get new ORA_ROWSCN. But how to know this is a deleted one.

Comment: If a row is deleted then it doesn't exist any more. Do you mean you can see rows with a changed ORA_ROWSCN (and don't have ROWDEPENDENCIES set for the table) and want to find out if that is because a row in the block was deleted, rather than inserted or updated? If so you should be looking for a timestamp column on the table and looking at existing rows - though that might not be definitive, and won't tell you anything about what might have been deleted; or the audit trail if it's set up with that granularity.

Comment: I have been exporting data from Oracle to Datalake with help of max(ORA_ROWSCN). When some inserts /Updates occur in Oracle table, i can see the ORA_ROWSCN  changes  in incremental fashion. So i will check and take again the max value of it and load all the data since last Max value. But if something got deleted from Oracle and how will i delete at my destination. I am loading data from datalake to sql table in incremental fashion. Fetching everytime latest data from oracle by using ORA_ROWSCN .

Comment: @mallikarjunappani Your approach will not capture deletions, and will also have problems capturing a complete transaction history in general. The only way to capture deletions will be a complete comparison of current primary keys to datalake primary keys. Build-your-own change data capture is not efficient.

Comment: You cannot obtain deleted rows from a table with a `select` statement, because those rows do not exist anymore for SQL interface (but may or may not exist physically in the storage structures).

Comment: You may create a separate table to log deletions and a trigger that will fire on `delete` and log PK values into this table. At the receiver side you'll need to (full) join your updated dataset (current increment) with the dataset of deleted rows and apply this resulting change to the target (with a `merge` statement)

Comment: Thanks pmdba and astentx. I will use another table which stores entire pk values and use them for comparing.